# Getting JPanels within other JPanels to left align

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I have an options JPanel which consists of 3 jpanels (which hold a JLabel and JRadio buttons). The 3 sub JPanels have the default layout.

The options panel has a BoxLayout on the Y Axis.

I then have the main gui which is a JFrame with a topPanel (using BorderLayout) which adds the options panel to itself using BorderLayout WEST.

My problem is that the options panel is stretched and the labels are center aligned.

Here is a image of what I mean.
I have what's on the left but want whats on the right.
[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note that any panel in a `BorderLayout` will be stretched vertically (`EAST`/`WEST`) or horizontally (`NORTH`/`SOUTH`) or both (`CENTER`) to fill the available space.  One way to constrain them, is to add them to the 'opposite alignment' panel.  E.G. something in `WEST` might be added to the `NORTH` of a constraining panel to compact it upwards.  Of course, there are some who hear this type of advice who add - 'or use a powerful layout manager'.  I'll leave it to them to flesh out that advice.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)? It is by far the most flexible and powerful Layout manager for swing/swt.